# Can I use xymatrix to make a spectral sequence ? How to make the boxes?

Tags: math-mode, xy-pic

Is it possible to use the xymatrix command to make a spectral sequence ? Since xymatrix has all the arrows, what I am really asking is are there commands that will enclose the entries in a lattice of boxes. A simple sample would be ideal.

Edit: An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen on the first page of [this paper](http://www.shef.ac.uk/nps/courses/bestiary/ss.pdf). Picture included here for completeness.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea as I don't use `xymatrix` but: 1) for general commutative diagrams, there is the `tikz-cd` package; 2) there is a `sseq` package  dedicated to typesetting all sorts of spectral sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to accomplish what I want with the packages that I have been using.

Comment: A pointer to an example of what you want to achieve would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The same pictures as in the paper, with only standard packages (in particular, `pict2e`) and no LAmS-TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(200,140)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 1, 0){190}}
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 0, 1){130}}
   \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){4}{\line( 1, 0){185}}
   \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){6}{\line( 0, 1){125}}
   \put( 23, 99){\vector( 4,-3){104}}
   \put( 75, 45){\makebox(0,0){$d_4$}}
   \put( 23,101){\vector( 2,-1){44}}
   \put( 45,101){\makebox(0,0){$d_2$}}
   \put( 15,105){\circle*{3}}
   \put( 75, 75){\circle*{3}}
   \put(135, 15){\circle*{3}}
   \put(195,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,135){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(230,110)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 1, 0){220}}
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 0, 1){100}}
   \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){3}{\line( 1, 0){215}}
   \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){7}{\line( 0, 1){95}}
   \multiput( 23, 41)(60, 0){3}{\line( 2,-1){44}}
   \put( 45, 41){\makebox(0,0){$d_2$}}
   \put( 15, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put( 75, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x$}}
   \put(135, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^2$}}
   \put(195, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^3$}}
   \put( 15, 45){\makebox(0,0){$u$}}
   \put( 75, 45){\makebox(0,0){$ux$}}
   \put(135, 45){\makebox(0,0){$ux^2$}}
   \put(195, 45){\makebox(0,0){$ux^3$}}
   \put(225,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,105){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(230,170)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 1, 0){220}}
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 0, 1){160}}
   \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){5}{\line( 1, 0){215}}
   \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){7}{\line( 0, 1){155}}
   \put( 15, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put( 75, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x$}}
   \put(135, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^2$}}
   \put(195, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^3$}}
   \put( 15, 75){\makebox(0,0){$y$}}
   \put( 75, 75){\makebox(0,0){$xy$}}
   \put(135, 75){\makebox(0,0){$x^2y$}}
   \put(195, 75){\makebox(0,0){$x^3y$}}
   \put( 15,135){\makebox(0,0){$y^2$}}
   \put( 75,135){\makebox(0,0){$xy^2$}}
   \put(135,135){\makebox(0,0){$x^2y^2$}}
   \put(195,135){\makebox(0,0){$x^3y^2$}}
   \put( 75,105){\makebox(0,0){$d_2y^2$}}
   \put(105, 75){\makebox(0,0){$d_3y^2$}}
   \put(135, 45){\makebox(0,0){$d_4y^2$}}
   \put(165, 15){\makebox(0,0){$d_5y^2$}}
   \put(225,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,165){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(200,170)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 1, 0){190}}
   \put(  0,  0){\vector( 0, 1){160}}
   \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){5}{\line( 1, 0){185}}
   \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){6}{\line( 0, 1){155}}
   \put( 15, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put( 15, 45){\makebox(0,0){$a_1$}}
   \put( 15,105){\makebox(0,0){$a_3$}}
   \put( 15,135){\makebox(0,0){$a_1a_3$}}
   \put(165, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put(165, 45){\makebox(0,0){$a_1u$}}
   \put(165,105){\makebox(0,0){$a_3u$}}
   \put(165,135){\makebox(0,0){$a_1a_3u$}}
   \put( 75, 75){\makebox(0,0){$d_2a_3$}}
   \put(105, 45){\makebox(0,0){$d_3a_3$}}
   \put(135, 15){\makebox(0,0){$d_4a_3$}}
   \put(195,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,165){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note: the picture may have some artifacts due to low resolution, the lines are right at higher resolution.)

Answer (score 1):

I have asked the author of that paper for the code.

Here are all four diagrams of that paper:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lamsarrow}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\usepackage{pb-lams}

\newsavebox{\cblob}
\savebox{\cblob}{
\begin{picture}(0,0)(3,0)
\put(0,0){\circle*{3.0}}
\end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(200,140)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 1, 0){185}}
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 0, 1){125}}
   {\lamstarget{0}
    \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){4}{\lamsvector( 1, 0){185}}
    \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){6}{\lamsvector( 0, 1){125}}}
   \put( 23, 99){\lamsvector( 4,-3){104}}
   \put( 75, 45){\makebox(0,0){$d_4$}}
   \put( 23,101){\lamsvector( 2,-1){44}}
   \put( 45,101){\makebox(0,0){$d_2$}}
   \put( 15,105){\usebox{\cblob}}
   \put( 75, 75){\usebox{\cblob}}
   \put(135, 15){\usebox{\cblob}}
   \put(190,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,130){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(230,110)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 1, 0){215}}
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 0, 1){95}}
   {\lamstarget{0}
    \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){3}{\lamsvector( 1, 0){215}}
    \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){7}{\lamsvector( 0, 1){95}}}
   \multiput( 23, 41)(60, 0){3}{\lamsvector( 2,-1){44}}
   \put( 45, 41){\makebox(0,0){$d_2$}}
   \put( 15, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put( 75, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x$}}
   \put(135, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^2$}}
   \put(195, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^3$}}
   \put( 15, 45){\makebox(0,0){$u$}}
   \put( 75, 45){\makebox(0,0){$ux$}}
   \put(135, 45){\makebox(0,0){$ux^2$}}
   \put(195, 45){\makebox(0,0){$ux^3$}}
   \put(220,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,100){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(230,170)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 1, 0){215}}
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 0, 1){155}}
   {\lamstarget{0}
    \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){5}{\lamsvector( 1, 0){215}}
    \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){7}{\lamsvector( 0, 1){155}}}
   \put( 15, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put( 75, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x$}}
   \put(135, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^2$}}
   \put(195, 15){\makebox(0,0){$x^3$}}
   \put( 15, 75){\makebox(0,0){$y$}}
   \put( 75, 75){\makebox(0,0){$xy$}}
   \put(135, 75){\makebox(0,0){$x^2y$}}
   \put(195, 75){\makebox(0,0){$x^3y$}}
   \put( 15,135){\makebox(0,0){$y^2$}}
   \put( 75,135){\makebox(0,0){$xy^2$}}
   \put(135,135){\makebox(0,0){$x^2y^2$}}
   \put(195,135){\makebox(0,0){$x^3y^2$}}
   \put( 75,105){\makebox(0,0){$d_2y^2$}}
   \put(105, 75){\makebox(0,0){$d_3y^2$}}
   \put(135, 45){\makebox(0,0){$d_4y^2$}}
   \put(165, 15){\makebox(0,0){$d_5y^2$}}
   \put(220,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,160){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
 \[ 
  \begin{picture}(200,170)(0,0)
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 1, 0){185}}
   \put(  0,  0){\lamsvector( 0, 1){155}}
   {\lamstarget{0}
    \multiput(  0, 30)( 0,30){5}{\lamsvector( 1, 0){185}}
    \multiput( 30,  0)(30, 0){6}{\lamsvector( 0, 1){155}}}
   \put( 15, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put( 15, 45){\makebox(0,0){$a_1$}}
   \put( 15,105){\makebox(0,0){$a_3$}}
   \put( 15,135){\makebox(0,0){$a_1a_3$}}
   \put(165, 15){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}
   \put(165, 45){\makebox(0,0){$a_1u$}}
   \put(165,105){\makebox(0,0){$a_3u$}}
   \put(165,135){\makebox(0,0){$a_1a_3u$}}
   \put( 75, 75){\makebox(0,0){$d_2a_3$}}
   \put(105, 45){\makebox(0,0){$d_3a_3$}}
   \put(135, 15){\makebox(0,0){$d_4a_3$}}
   \put(190,  0){\makebox(0,0){$s$}}
   \put(  0,160){\makebox(0,0){$t$}}
  \end{picture} 
 \]
\end{document}
```

He does not use `xy-pic` but I do not think that this here is a use case for a commutative diagram. Please have a look, if this code helps you for reproduction of such images. If not, you will have to tell us more about what you are trying to achieve.

If you are trying to combine commutative diagrams and such grids, I would absolutely recommend to take a look on `tikz-cd`